# How do I manage thread shutdown in a multithreaded crawler?

Tags: c++, multithreading, architecture, queue

Let's say I'm writing a mulithreaded web crawler. Threads get a job (for example, in a form of URL) from a queue, do some work, and then might add some new jobs to the queue. Sounds simple enough, but I'm not sure how to handle the situation where all the jobs are done. Let's say there are currently 0 jobs in the queue, and some thread is trying to get a new job. At this point two situations are possible:

- Some other threads are working and might actually produce new jobs for this thread to get. In this case, it is probably possible to just wait for a new task (with a blocking .pop(), if the queue supports it, or just by sleeping and waking up time to time to check if a job is available)
- All other threads are also waiting for a job. In this case, no new jobs can be produced, so threads must be terminated.

One solution I can think of is having an integer (behind a mutex), which should serve as a number of "busy" threads - it will be increased when thread gets a job, and decreased once it is finished processing it. This way, if there is 0 jobs and 0 threads working, a thread can safely be terminated. However, I'm not sure it is the best solution possible. Are there any other options to handle such a situation?

Comment: _"...a thread can safely be terminated..."_ it is not possible to safely terminate a thread from another thread.  Each thread should check to see if it can close itself.  You could even queue a job to the queue that asks the threads to exit.

Comment: Typically you have a main thread controlling the job queue.  It signals a semaphore when a job is added, which wakes up a waiting thread.  The thread does its work and then waits again.  You can use the same semaphore to wake up _all_ threads, and have them test a shutdown flag that you have set (correctly managed with a mutex of course).  Then they know to quit.  Threads also test this _before_ waiting.  After the main thread signals shutdown, it waits on all workers.  Same mechanism can distinguish between "process remaining jobs before quit" and "quit immediately".

Comment: If any thread can add jobs to the queue, you need to also have threads update a counter when processing.  That way, threads can ensure they don't quit until shutdown _and_ no threads processing.

Comment: Your mutex-protected counter sbould work ok.  The thread that finishes processing the last page would decrement it to zero and so completion would be detected.  Should you need to, you could submit a kill message to the queue that would instruct any thread getting it to requeue the message and terminate, so blowing away all the threads.  I like to use a null for the poison pill - it does not need to be freed at the end:)